# Messages does not get deleted?

Tags: c#, bots, chatbot, discord, discord.net

```
Service.CreateCommand("delete")
       .Do(async (e) => {
           var MessageToDelete = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(150);
           await e.Channel.DeleteMessages(MessageToDelete);
});
```

I am trying to make my bot delete 150 messages when I do the command. But when I test the command, it doesn't work and the bot does nothing. I tried using a try-catch statement on it already and it always moves to the catch block. Is there anyway to fix this?

Also, how do I make that only users who can delete messages can use this command?

Comment: What's the exceptions it throws?

Comment: It just threw an exception. I just tried placing the catch block on 2 different lines and it mostly catched at `var MessageToDelete = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(150);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take a look at this picture :

[image]

The limit of the messages you can download is 100. Meaning that if you try to download more, it will result in an error. If you want to delete 150 messages, you can make it perform the task twice through looping or manually copying and pasting the 2 lines of code again. [Do not loop it too many times without a timer, your bot may get rate-limited.]

> Also, how do I make that only users who can delete messages can use this command?

Using `if..else` statement, `if (e.User.ServerPermissions.ManageMessages == true)`...

You can also do this for the rest like banning and stuff, etc, its just simply `e.User.ServerPermissions.<PERMISSIONS>`

I recommending on reading up more on your discord.net library through github [here](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net).